# how i can get order id and customer name in oberserver magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, magento2.2.6, customer-name

I have used event

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
```

> when I use this code I am getting null $order

```
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();   // im getting null
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        $this->_logger->info($order_id);
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
            $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId();

            $proName[] = $item->getName(); // product name
        }
        $this->logger->info($ProdustIds);
        $customer = $order->getCustomerId();
```

how I can get order id and customer name in Magento 2???

Comment: which version ypu are using?

Comment: magento 2.2.6 bro

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get order id on  `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`
then you have to call **`$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()`**

**`$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()`** provide **an array** which consist of one order id of single checkout and provide multiple order ids.

```
 <?php

nameSpace YourNameSpace;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use usMagento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
class OrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
   \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
   ) {

       $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
            return;
        } 
        foreach($orderIds as $orderId){

            try{
                $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
                if ($order->getCustomerFirstname()) {
                    $customerName = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
                } else {
                    $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname(). ' ' . $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
                }
                //$customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $ex) {

            }


        }
   }
}
```

Comment: but customer name shows as guest......

Comment: The answer is updated. I have added a condition,

Comment: @AmitBera will it make any performance issue if we use $this0->orderRepository->get($orderID) inside loop ? if we need only createddate ,do you think it is good to load the entire order data ?

Answer (score 0):

To get order ID change your code like below :

```
    $order_ids  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    $order_id   = $order_ids[0];
```

To get Shipping Adress load order:

```
//\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
$_order =  $this->orderRepository->get($order->getEntityId());

$shippingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress();
 $shippingName = $shippingAddress->getFirstName().$shippingAddress->getLastName();
```

Comment: Because shipping name can be anythings. You can't say shipping name will be always current customer name.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: $order

Comment: $order->getEntityId() should be your order_id In this case it will be $order_id.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, Please find below code.
To get customer name find the code below.

```
$customer = $observer->getData('data_object');
 if ($customer) {
      $customerName = $customer->getFirstName();
   }
```

To get the order use the code below:

```
$observer->getOrder()
```

Comment: i'm getting null bro in $customer variaable